# I need to set an exact location for my image but it doesn't move?

Tags: java, image, location, frame, jlabel

I'm making a game and having a few issues. For right now I got the image/character I wanna use on the frame but it appears on top of the screen and it doesn't move.I need to be able to use coordinates to be able to place where I want to.I've looked everywhere but none of the codes look similar to mine. Also I'm very new to Java so please be specific as possible.
Here's my code:

First Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JumpyBoy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Boy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (1000, 700));
        Boy panel = new Boy();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The image's class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
public class Boy extends JPanel {

    JLabel Boy1;
    ImageIcon Boy;

    public Boy () {
        setBackground (Color.white);

        Boy = new ImageIcon("Boy.png");
        Boy1 = new JLabel (Boy, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Dimension size = Boy1.getPreferredSize();
        Boy1.setBounds(200, 400, 32, 321);
        //right here what should I do ^

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add (Boy1);
        add (panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing makes extensive use of layout managers, which make it possible to design dynamic user interfaces which can work on multiple platforms and rendering environments.

While possible, it's not easy, to use components in this way.

First, you need to remove the pre-existing layout manager.  By default `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`, this is, in part, what's interfering with your attempts...

```
public Boy() {
    setLayout(null);
```

By doing this, you become responsible for the positioning of the components with in the panel.

Next, you don't need the `JPanel` within `Boy` to hold the `JLabel`, instead, just add `Boy1` to the `Boy` panel.

```
Boy1 = new JLabel (Boy, SwingConstants.CENTER);
Boy1.setBounds(200, 400, 32, 321);

// This doesn't make sense...
//JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//panel.add (Boy1);
add (Boy1);
```

Be prepared for all kinds of weirdness.

Having said all that, typically, you wouldn't do this for games, it's not the most efficient method for rendering content, but look simple, but there's a bit of overhead involved.

Typically, instead, you would render the content directly to a `Graphics` context, this gives you much more control of the layering and positing of your artifacts.

Take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details...

Comment: thank you for being so specific, i'll try it in a minute and give the news. And honestly I know you wouldn't really use this for a game but it's all we've learned. I'm taking Java 1 in my high school.The game is gonna be like flappy bird 2d but a kid on the ground jumping everytime there is a rock or something in the way. Very simple.

Comment: add boy1 to the boy panel? but i dont have a boy panel.Boy is the image itself. i did the null thing and image doesnt show up anymore. im guessing its because of this.

Comment: No, add it directly the `Boy` class (panel), don't bother with adding the `JLabel` to another `JPanel` and then adding that to the `Boy` pane

Comment: This might seem unrelated but could I possibly have your email? I was planning on taking Java very seriously this summer and possibly get into Android App making. Would be a honor to have someone help me when there's a little ditch in the way. It's completely fine if you don't have the time or can't. Would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't be coding a game, or anything with a gui when you are new to java. Second, in order to move it, just call setBounds again with different coordinates.